# Juju - Restart application after system reboot

Tags: ubuntu, kubeflow, juju, charmed-kubernetes

I'm trying to get to know how Kubeflow works and the most accessible solution to me was setting up a Ubuntu virtual machine and install Kubeflow there with Charm/Juju. I'm following [this](https://charmed-kubeflow.io/docs/quickstart) guide.

Everything goes fine and I'm able to set up the application, however sometimes I need to shut down the machine, and in the documentation I can't seem to find how to restart a deployed application. And of course purging and reinstalling each time doesn't make much sense.

So the question is, once I deploy Kubeflow as per the above guide and shut the VM off, how can I restart Kubeflow on the VM (once it's restarted)?